# Using Winforms, my program does not execute in the correct screen size

Tags: c#, resize, screen

I had a program that I used to execute in a computer with a screen of 1366 * 768, but now I changed into another one of 1920 * 1080. In my ancient computer it was OK, but now some objects are misplaced (I am using the command 'this.Location = new Point(x,y)'. I tried changing the code to adapt to the new screen size, but they stay misplaced, just in another way.

Does somebody know how to adapt the program to the new size?

Thank you so much

Comment: I don't think you typically have to worry about screen resolution in winforms. Can you share a reproducible example of what the problem is?

Comment: Sounds like you haven't really made correct use of the Anchor and/or Dock properties. Need to see a screenshot to know for sure, but I'm reasonably certain that if you write code that specifies the .Location of a Control then something went wrong with your process because the forms designer normally does all that

Comment: [High DPI support in Windows Forms](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/high-dpi-support-in-windows-forms?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#configuring-your-windows-forms-app-for-high-dpi-support)